# Reverse UDP Proxy from Public IP to Public IP

Tags: debian, networking, ip

is it possible to set up an reverse UDP Proxy to route the Traffic from my VPS in the Cloud to my Homeserver behind my router?(Port Forwarding, Port Triggering all possible)

I am not entirely sure if this is even possible i am not that into networking.

I have googled a bit and found "solutions" with nginx, but that was all for reverse proxying Webservers.

The Deal here is i want to run a Teamspeak Server on my Homeserver without exposing my Home IP.

Appreciate every answer.

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: Homeserver is running Debian and VPS is running Debian aswell.

Comment: Would a socks proxy on the VPS do? You'd have to explicitly connect to it. Otherwise please add more details on "Traffic from VPS". Which kind of traffic? It can't be **all** traffic, otherwise the VPS wouldn't be reachable any longer. Or you need two public IPs.

Comment: Hello, it would be UDP Traffic from Port 9987(Teamspeak VOICE IP) from VPS to Homeserver. Is a Socks not an Specific Proxy for HTTP/HTTPS communication? CAn i use a Socks proxy to forward traffic over port 9987 to my Homeserver?

Comment: If it's a single port, use iptables rules for port forwarding (google, there's lots of tutorials). [SOCKS5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS5) can forward UDP packets, but not in the form "UDP packets to a particular port".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is via [iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables). What port you must forwad are [here](https://support.teamspeak.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002712257-Which-ports-does-the-TeamSpeak-3-server-use-).